# how to Create Javadoc with Class Diagrams in netbeans gradle

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, javadoc

i done my term project but my professor said you need Class Diagrams with UML class diagram using yWorksUMLDoclet community edition. i know how to do it in normal java app, but i dont konw how to add additional javadoc options in netbeans gradle.

technical my professor want Class Diagrams so now i put [this code](https://github.com/kercheval/GradleCMPlugin/wiki/Create-Javadoc-with-Class-Diagrams-using-UMLGraph-with-Gradle) in my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}


allprojects {  apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "java"

    configurations {
        umljavadoc
    }

    dependencies {
        umljavadoc 'org.umlgraph:umlgraph:5.6'
    }
    task javadoc(overwrite: true, dependsOn: compileJava) {
        setDescription('Generates Javadoc API documentation with UMLGraph diagrams')
        setGroup(JavaBasePlugin.DOCUMENTATION_GROUP)

        doLast {
            def javaFilePath = file('C:/Users/khunjuice/Desktop/java project')
            if (javaFilePath.exists()) {
                ant.javadoc(classpath: (configurations.runtime + configurations.provided).asPath, 
                            sourcepath: file('C:/Users/khunjuice/Desktop/java project'), 
                            packagenames: '*',
                            destdir: "${docsDir}/javadoc",
                            private: 'true',
                            docletpath: configurations.umljavadoc.asPath) {
                    doclet(name: 'org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc') {
                        param(name: '-inferrel')
                        param(name: '-inferdep')
                        param(name: '-qualify')
                        param(name: '-postfixpackage')
                        param(name: '-hide', value: 'java.*')
                        param(name: '-collpackages', value: 'java.util.*')
                        param(name: '-nodefontsize', value: '9')
                        param(name: '-nodefontpackagesize', value: '7')
                        param(name: '-link', value: 'http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec')
                        param(name: '-link', value: 'http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/api')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'my-gdx-game'
        gdxVersion = '1.4.1'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-alpha-04'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.4.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')}
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

but noting happen

Comment: The documentation of the gradle javadoc task has an example showing how to use a custom doclet. Read it, read the documentation, and try something: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html

Comment: I am new with gradle. i use it because LibGdx

Comment: That's precisely because you're new to it that you need to read the documentation and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case console command `gradlew javadoc` in project's root folder generates documentation.